# How to use variable that are set inside a function within a for loop or a if-block in python

Tags: python, function, if-statement, variables, scope

I want to be able to use the BestELevator variable outside the findElevator function (In python)

```
userPosition = int(input('Enter the position of the user: '))
userDirection = str(input('Enter the direction floor (up/down): '))


elevatorList = {
           1: {'position':'6', 'direction':'down', 'status':'move', 'gap':'', 'priority':''} ,   
           2: {'position':'-6', 'direction':'up'  , 'status':'idle', 'gap':'', 'priority':''}
}

def findElevator(userPosition, userDirection):
  for i in elevatorList:
    elevatorPosition = int(elevatorList[i]['position'])
    elevatorDirection = str(elevatorList[i]['direction'])
    if (elevatorPosition == userPosition) & (elevatorDirection == userDirection):
      elevatorList[i]['priority'] = 55
      bestElevator = elevatorList[i]
      return bestElevator
    else:
      print('doesnt work ')

findElevator(userPosition, userDirection)
print(bestElevator)
```

Comment: Use `and` instead of `&` here.

Comment: You are returning this variable from the function already... Simply assign the return value to another variable: `best_elevator = findElevator(userPosition, userDirection)`

Comment: Thank you @Daniel, it works better now!

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bestElevator = findElevator(userPosition, userDirection)
print(bestElevator)
```

The Variable bestElevator inside the if block is only accesible inside the function it was defined.